# Are there 18650 cells with 1000+ cycle life?

Tags: lithium-ion

Most cells I looked at have 500 cycles (up to 80% initial capacity). A few have 1000. Are there any 18650 (or bigger) with at least 3000 cycles? Or is 18650 somehow now capable of better cycle life because of its shape?

Comment: You can substantially increase the number of cycles by avoiding charging to rated charge capacity or discharging to rated levels. The extremes of charging and discharging levels have the greatest impact upon battery life.

Comment: 1000+ is very different from 3000+

Comment: 18650 is a battery size, not a battery type. Can you clarify which type you mean?

Answer (score 2):

While product recommendations aren't allowed on EE.SE, I think this information might still answer your question.

The cycle life of a rechargeable battery is determined by its chemistry, not by its form factor. 18650 cells don't just have a higher or lower cycle life than other cells just because of their shape. Cylindrical, prismatic and pouch cells are all limited in their cycle life simply by the chemicals inside of them.

That said, I believe that you are talking about Li-Ion (or Li-Polymer) cells, specifically ones with NMC or LMO chemistry (3.7V). These cells have been optimized for the highest possible energy density. Of course, high energy density doesn't come for free - there are trade-offs involved. The high energy density is only achievable by using very reactive anode and cathode materials while operating the cell at high voltage, which causes large electrochemical stresses on its components (specifically, on the electrolyte). That, in turn, means that the chemistry of these cells deteriorates quickly when they're cycled.

Other chemistries aren't as aggressive as the typical 3.7V Li-Ion stuff. LiFePo cells, for example, have a longer cycle life simply because their internal chemistry is more stable - but of course that comes at the cost of reduced energy density. Their capacity and voltage is generally lower than Li-Ion (typical voltage around 3.2V) but you can expect to get around 2000 cycles out of these cells (often more).

If you really want extreme cycle life, you might want to go to even lower energy density chemistries, such as Lithium Titanate (LTO). These cells operate at 2.4V and a typical 18650 LTO cell has around 1300mAh - so their energy density is around a third of that of a typical 18650 Li-Ion cell, meaning that you will need three times the number of cells to reach the same overall energy content of your battery pack. The upside of LTO cells is that they almost don't degrade over time - some manufacturers rate their cells for 10k+ cycles and a shelf life of more than 30 years. (The other downside is that they're still quite hard to get and very expensive.)

TL;DR: If you want long life, choose less aggressive cell chemistries with necessarily lower energy density.

Comment: but there are NMC cells (pouch) with 6000+ cycle life already. I think it's because 18650 manufacturers are stuck with older 2000s technology, so there are no (or at least I didnt find) modern cells.

Comment: I haven't heard of such a cell yet, could you give me a link to it? The thing is, modern 18650 cells are just the insides of a pouch cell rolled up... So there's absolutely no difference between them.

Comment: @RiDi I know people inside battery acquisition departments for large companies in need of very reliable batteries in large amounts. The thing you claim about "18650 manufacturers are stuck with older…" is absolute nonsense. As Jonathan S said, form factor has absolutely nothing to do with it. The choices you make with a battery targeting a specific market and thus specific application requirements is.